# one to one relationship with JPA specification using custom ID generators

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

When need to map a one to one relationship in using JPA with hibernate, the @GenericGenerator annotation which is a hibernate specific annotation.

```
    @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "foreign", 
            parameters = @Parameter(name = "property", value = "stock"))
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
    int id;
```

Since the best practice to use JPA specification, isn't there a annotation in JPA similar as @GenericGenerator in hibernate?

Comment: your question is unclear. pls be more precise in what you're trying to achieve. 1:1 mapping is one topic, generating IDs is another...

Answer (score 0):

There is, and it's described in the [hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#d5e2779):

> Finally, you can ask Hibernate to copy the identifier from another associated entity. In the Hibernate jargon, it is known as a foreign generator but the JPA mapping reads better and is encouraged.

```
@Entity
class MedicalHistory implements Serializable {
  @Id @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "person_id")
  Person patient;
}

@Entity
public class Person implements Serializable {
  @Id @GeneratedValue Integer id;
}
```

> Or alternatively

```
@Entity
class MedicalHistory implements Serializable {
  @Id Integer id;

  @MapsId @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "patient_id")
  Person patient;
}

@Entity
class Person {
  @Id @GeneratedValue Integer id;
}
```